# Compiling Mathematica script in Latex

Tags: latex

I am writing a report in physics and I want to use a *Mathematica* script that produce something like a simulation. I want to know how I can add this code to my LaTeX file, so when I compile that LaTeX file, I can see the simulations in the resultant PDF file.

Comment: LaTeX is clearly not an interpreter for Mathematica. I'm not sure, what extent of interactivity may be possible within a pdf. In fact, when a colleague of mine was publishing a paper, he had some interactive content as online supplementary material in a separate Java applet.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I do not agree with the downvote, but I think you will be better off to ask this on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/). In place of *Mathematica*, you could have almost any language other than $\TeX$ and the answer would be much the same.

Comment: 1) Write the Latex document using [Wolfram Language template tags](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WorkingWithTemplates.html). 2) Write a command line script that first runs the Wolfram Language interpreter on the file, thus evaluating the WL code, and then runs the Latex compiler, thus creating the PDF.

Comment: @Pickett would, say, a `Manipulate` be preserved as an interactive thing though? Else one may just as well export output cells to pdf and embed into latex.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I don't think the OP is talking about dynamic frontend stuff, the way I interpret it is that he just wants to be able to use Mathematica code in his Latex code so that results are generated on the fly. "one may just as well export output cells to pdf and embed into latex" I don't know what that means, I described a way to create a hybrid WL/Latex document that can be compiled with a single command.